# Prove that for all ints m and n, and int d is positive then (m+n) mod d = ((m mod d) + (n mod d)) mod d

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I can also use the fact that we already know (m+dk) mod d = m mod d. Also given the hint to use b = m mod d and c = n mod d and think about how I can compare those to m+n. I've been stuck for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write Euclidean divisions:
$$m=dq_m+r_m$$
$$n=dq_n+r_n$$
Add them up:
$$m+n=d(q_m+q_n)+r_m+r_n$$
Therefore $(m+n)-(r_m+r_n)$ is a multiple of $d$.

Comment: Thanks ! I cant believe I didn't think of writing and adding m and n in that form.